# Iterate using an enum

Tags: c++, c++11, enums

I have `std::map` which its key is an enum like this:

```
enum class my_enum{a=1,b,c,d};
std::map<my_enum,my_class> my_map;
```

I want to iterate over the map so I used this `for`:

```
for (auto current_type = (id_type)0;
     (int)current_type < 4;
     current_type = (my_enum)((int)current_type + 1)){
   //do things
}
```

I think it is rubbish. Do you have a better suggestion?

**EDIT:**

I am totally aware of using of iterators. I know they are prefereable. However, for some reason, I have to stick to the regular index-based `for`.

Comment: Have you consulted some [reference documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) for iteration facilities offered by `std::map` (`begin()`, `end()` etc.)? Have you tried applying that? What obstacles have you encountered?

Comment: Of course, I forget to mention that, I am going to edit

Comment: You can use iterators with a "regular `for`." It's quite unclear what your limitations are. Can you explain in a bit more detail?

Comment: Not necessarily the best way, but unscoped `enum` would at least avoid the horrible casts... which, if you must keep them, should be `static_cast<DstType>(src)` anyway as this is C++ after all.

Comment: @Angew You are right again, but just please suppose I can not.

Comment: What is a "regular" `for` loop?  As far as I am concerned `for (auto it = my_map.begin(), it != my_map.end(), ++it){}` is a "regular" for loop

Comment: `for (const auto& p : my_map)`, is that a regular for? It isn't clear at all why you need to iterate using the enumeration values. And if you do, then what is the connection to that problem with a map?

Comment: It is problem in the design. where the enum index(integer value) has its meaning. and I do not want to fix a lot of things which are out of my scope

Comment: This question has been downvoted and has been voted to close because the stupidity of the idea that I am trying to do. However, we all know that in the real life we have to adopt a rubbish code and work from a point where we do not have an option of fixing what was before it. I think downvotes should be about the clearness of the question not because we hate the way that the OP handle his/her problem :)
and Many thanks for your time helping me in this :)

Comment: Sorry, but the question it totally unclear, probably because of the irrelevant map thing. How do you know why people down-voted anyway?

Comment: @juanchopanza maybe you are right. However, I could get a satisfied answer from someone..

Comment: it is not duplicated. that question handel the case of enums not enums class. and there is only one anser about it and it is exactly as my bad approch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your types like this:

```
enum class my_enum{a=1, b, c, d, END};
std::map<my_enum,my_class> my_map;

my_enum& operator++( my_enum &val ) {
  using IntType = typename std::underlying_type<my_enum>::type
  val = static_cast<my_enum>( static_cast<IntType>(val) + 1 );
  return val;
}
```

And then you can use them like this:

```
for (my_enum e = my_enum::a; e < my_enum::END; ++e) {
   my_class c = my_map[e];
   ....
}
```

(Although, you might prefer to use something other that operator[] if you don't want to create null-values for entries that don't exist.)

Comment: What do you do if some header defines a macro named `END`?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Add a header that defines a macro named `class`, and run away.

Comment: @ams: Just by conforming to the usual C++ convention and avoiding the all uppercase name, you can avoid that problem. No advantage in the Java-ism. Only problems, and code that shouts.

Answer (score 3):

To iterate over a map `m`:

```
for( auto& item : m ) ...
```

To iterate over your `enum class` values:

```
#include <initializer_list>

enum class my_enum{a=1,b,c,d};

auto main() -> int
{
    using E = my_enum;
    for( my_enum const id : {E::a, E::b, E::c, E::d} ) {}
}
```

or

```
enum class my_enum{a=1,b,c,d};

auto main() -> int
{
    for( int i = int( my_enum::a ); i <= int( my_enum::d ); ++i )
    {
        auto const id = my_enum( i );
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have a range class at hand, yes. Otherwise just an `int` loop control variable and cast it in the loop body. Added example to the answer.

Comment: @HumamHelfawi if your map contains all 4 enum values, then you can just use range-for loop.